# How to get multiple resultset from single tDBinput in Talend?

Tags: talend

In talend open studio, which component should I use to call my stored procedure, which returns multiple resultsets?

Most of the component only has a single output.

Comment: How are you planning to process the multiple resultsets in the rest of your Talend job if you can get a Talend component to return them?

Comment: Yes. planned to do insert of the resultsets to different database tables. Which talend component can return them. I can use tjava to manually do it. But if there is a component available it will ve better.

Comment: Hi - the short answer is that you can't do what you are trying to do. With Talend (and every other ETL tool I'm aware of) each job that you build takes a source dataset, transforms it in some way and then writes it to a target - so you can't process multiple datasets in the same component (or in the same data flow). The only way I can think of getting your process to work would be to run the SP first and get it to write each result set to a different table and then create a separate job to process each of these source tables

Comment: As an aside, it normally not a good idea to mix two types of data transformation tools in one process. Either use Talend or use Stored Procedures but don't use both in the same process. The SP components in ETL tools are normally used to return a single value for a given set of inputs - not multiple values and definitely not different datasets

Comment: Thank you very much for the input.